# MDX - icCube -How can i create the Known mdx entity(An event) between a Pie Chart and a Histogram

Tags: events, mdx, iccube

My icCube report contains a Pie Chart( 5 top client + "Other") and a histogram, when I select a client on Pie Chart, the histogram change.

Using the following mdx In my Pie Chart

```
WITH   

CATEGORY CALCULATED MEMBER [Client].[Client].[All].[Autre] AS SubCubeComplement( TopCount ( Order ( [Client].[Client].[idclient] ,[Measures].[venteT] , DESC ) ,5) )   

SELECT { NONEMPTY([Measures].[venteT]),[Measures].[DateC] }  ON 0 ,
   { NONEMPTY(TopCount ( Order ( [Client].[Client].[idclient]     ,[Measures].[venteT] , DESC ) ,5)),NONEMPTY({[Client].[Client].[All].[Autre]})} ON 1 
FROM (SELECT { @{dated![Time].[Time].[Jour]} } ON 0 FROM [CubeVente] )
where{Tail([Statvente].[Statvente].[statVente])}
CELL PROPERTIES VALUE
```

Using the following mdx In my Histogram

```
SELECT
{ Order( [Statut].[Statut].[statut].allmembers, [Measures].[DateC], BASC) } * { @{clientv![Client].[Client]} } ON COLUMNS,
{ NonEmpty( Order( [Time].[Time].[Année].allmembers, [Measures].[DateC], BASC), [Measures].[DateC]) } ON ROWS
FROM ( SELECT 
{ @{dated![Time].[Time].[Jour]} } ON 0 FROM [CubeVente])
```

But when I select the cell "Other" in the PieChart, there is an error:

> '[Client].[Client].[All-M].[Autre]' n'est pas une entité MDX connue

Is there a way to resolve this error? Txs, Marwen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create the category member on both charts so it's recognized in the histogram charts (don't forget the where clause content).

Note that you can combine the event with an mdx [IIF](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Iif.php) function.

I don't see an easy way to do this properly as the category is created dynamically during the MDX evaluation.

Comment: Ok i will try  to create the catégorie on both charts, In facts i don't need to show the result of the cell "Other" on the Histogram, i would ask you if there is a solution to make it non selectable on the Pie Chart (not clickable)

Comment: I don't think it's possible,